# How to unit test StripeJs in karma Angular8

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to unit test a payment component that uses `StripeJS`.

I import it in file 'ng-app.js':

```
stripe: /*@ngInject*/ function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    type: 'js',
                    path: 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/'
                  });
                }
```

Inside my payment component (`payment.component.ts`) I use:

```
import {StripeJS} from 'stripejs';
```

```
import {ElementFactory, OnChange, StripeElement} from 'stripejs/element';
```

And also:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.stripe = window.Stripe(window.properties.stripePKs[this.carrier]);
    this.createStripeElements(this.stripe.elements());
  }
```

But I don't know how to MOCK the `StripeJS` inside the `payment.component.spec.ts`.

The component is `undefined` when I do `component = fixture.componentInstance;`

My request is to know how to combine the `StripeJS` in the test as Mock or not in order for me to succeed creating the component for the rest of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I ave never used stripeJS, SO i am going to give you a general answer and if you need a concrete example then post your code here or on a github and we can assist you in more details. You need to understad how jasmine and Karma work before unit testing. 
In your import section of the unit test, make sure stripeJS is imported. 
in you UT constructor have something like
    `mockstripejs:Mock<StripeJS>`
in your test class where you have test, you need to set up the stripe operation you want to test, if it something like `stripe.getcardprovider`, then you need a setup like `mockstripejs.setup(x=>x.getcardprovider).is(cardProvider.Object)`
where cardProvider is the object you want returned
I hope this help.